# $0\to L\to R^{n}\to M \to 0$ is exact, prove $M$ is finitely presented if and only if $L$ is finitely generated.

Tags: commutative-algebra

Suppose $R$ is a ring, $0 \rightarrow L\rightarrow R^{n} \rightarrow M \rightarrow 0$ is a short exact sequence, prove $M$ is finitely presented if and only if $L$ is finitely generated.

Comment: What is your definition of finitely presented? This can be taken to be the definition of finite presentation in fact. If you mean that $M$ is given by finitely many generators with finitely many relations between them, then that $L$ are the relations. Am I misunderstanding the question?

Comment: the definition is: $M $ is finitely presented if $\ni$ exact sequence $R^{m}\to R^{n}\to M \to 0$ where $m,n \in \mathbb{N}$

Comment: @DhruvRanganathan: Dear Dhruv, I don't think this would ever be the *definition* of f.p.  The point is that f.p. is about the existence of *some* finite presentation, while this question then aims at showing that if $M$ is f.p., then *every* finite generating set has a f.g. module of relations.  Of course, they are equivalent; that is what this question is about.  But the second condition is useless as a definition until you have proved this equivalence, since you can't check it (without proving the equivalence).  Regards,

Comment: @DhruvRanganathan: P.S. Seeing your answer below, I guess that you are well aware of the issue in the preceding comment, so sorry about that.  I just wanted it to be clear to anyone looking at this that the key points is to show that *some* finite generating set of a module having a f.g. module of relations implies that *every* finite generating set has the same property.

Comment: I learned of this results for the case of groups from the paper of B. H. Neumann,  *Some remarks on infinite groups*, J. London Math. Soc. 
**12** (1937), 120-127. I needed it for some work of mine on (graded) Lie algebras, but it was really the same thing. I understand this is by now a standard result in universal algebra.

Comment: @Matt, of course you are right. I figured this out in the time between my comment and my answer. I mixed up "definition" with "how I like thinking about it" - which is a dangerous thing to do of course. Thanks for point out my error.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is a sketch of a proof.

Suppose that $M$ is finitely presented (as defined in Alex's comment to my question). Choose a presentation $R^m\to R^n\to M\to0$.

Claim: For any epimorphism $\phi:R^l\to M$, $\ker \phi$ is finitely generated.

Proof: We have two sequences

$R^m\to R^n\to M\to 0$

$0\to K\to R^l\to M\to 0$.

Imagine an identity map between the $M$ on the top and bottom. There exists a map $\alpha:R^n\to R^l$ making the right square above. To see this, pick a basis and chase a diagram - this is not hard and a good exercise. This in turn furnishes a morphism $R^m\to K$ (top to bottom).

Now we're in good shape, we can use the snake lemma, to get an isomorphism $cok(R^m\to K)\cong cok(R^m\to R^l$). We can conclude that the cokernel is finite as an $R$-module. This tells us that $K$ is actually finitely generated (do you see why? Even though $R^m$ doesnt surject onto $K$, there's only "finite amount of stuff" left).

So thats one direction. The other one should be easy I believe: if you have a finitely generated kernel, you can pick a finite rank free module to map onto that, which produces the presentation you want.

Also, see this interesting and nearly identical discussion on MO: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/1788/does-finitely-presented-mean-always-finitely-presented-answered-yes. Brian Conrad's answer is wonderfully instructive and worth reading!

Comment: Dear Dhruv, There is a typo in your second $cok$; $R^m$ should be $R^n$. Regards,